# Wrap custom terms loop

Tags: terms

I have a custom terms loop, that gets category images and links.

```
<?php 
foreach (get_terms( 'razotajs', 'orderby=count&order=DESC&hide_empty=0&parent=0' ) as $cat) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'razotajs'); ?>" title="<?php echo $cat->name; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" alt="<?php echo $cat->name; ?>" />
    </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I need to wrap each 6 categories `a` in `logo_sets` div. I use Circle2 slider plugin with html data attributes, if i use JQ split and wrap function, slider dont work. Is there a way to add wrap in loop?

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired HTML output?

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution, split in arrays:

```
<?php
            foreach (array_chunk(get_terms( 'razotajs', 'orderby=count&order=DESC&hide_empty=0&parent=0' ), 6, true) as $array)
            {
                echo '<div class="logo_sets">';
                foreach($array as $cat)
                { ?>
                     <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'razotajs'); ?>" title="<?php echo $cat->name; ?>"><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" alt="<?php echo $cat->name; ?>" /></a>
                <?php }
                echo '</div>';
            }
            ?>
```